# How to convert plain English into composed logical conditions?

Tags: java, logic

I have 7 boolean variables name

```
A1
A2
A3

B1
B2
B3

C
```

Now the condition should evaluate to true if

- at least one of A and at least one of B is true

or

- C and at least one of A and B is true

I don't know exactly how I can make a short composed condition out of this:

Any hints how to start?

Comment: "at least one of" means "OR them together", "all of" means "AND them together"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a context, so I am going by your tags and assuming you are writing this in Java.  Below is the code you would use to evaluate the 2 conditional tests you posed.

For "At least one of A and one of B":

```
bool condition1 = (A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)
```

For "C and at least one of A and B is true" (reading this as A & B variables are being tested as one):

```
bool condition2 = C && (A1 || A2 || A3 || B1 || B2 || B3)
```

Answer (score 1):

"At least one of" can also be written as "not none of", so:

```
!(!B1 && !B2 && !B3)
```

This can also be written as (applying [De Morgan's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Rule)):

```
B1 || B2 || B3
```

The rest of what you've specified can more or less be translated directly, with appropriate use of `&&`, `||`, and parentheses to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)`
2. `((A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)) && C`

Comment: OP has specified Java, so you should probably use `||` and `&&` rather than `+` and `*`.

Comment: oh, didn't see the java tag. Was assuming logic theory.

Answer (score 1):

At least one means you have to OR them

so your first condition wouwld be (A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)

Answer (score 1):

- "at least one" = OR = `||`
- "and" = AND = `&&`

Therefore the two parts are:

- `(A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)`

or

- `C && (A1 || A2 || A3 || B1 || B2 || B3)`

Therefore:

```
boolean R = ((A1 || A2 || A3) && (B1 || B2 || B3)) || (C && (A1 || A2 || A3 || B1 || B2 || B3));
```

Slightly easier on the eye (and, perhaps, the mind):

```
boolean T1 = (A1 || A2 || A3);
boolean T2 = (B1 || B2 || B3);

boolean R = (T1 && T2) || (C && (T1 || T2));
```

Answer (score 1):

at least one of A and at least one of B is true
or

C and at least one of A and B is true

( (a1 || a2 || a3) && (b1 || b2 || b3) ) || (c && ( (a1 || a2 || a3) && (b1 || b2 || b3) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
isTrue = ( ((A1 || A2 || A3) && ( B1 || B2 || B3)) || 

         ( C && ( (A1 || A2 || A3) && ( B1 || B2 || B3) ) ) )
```

The question is not very clear for the second part:

C and at least one of A and B = C or at least one of A and at least one of B ?

If that is the case, some answers are incorrect.

C and ( A1 and !B1) should evaluate to False, while some expressions in answers will evaluate to true.